# div is not viewd

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

this is the Html :

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="myDiv" align="right">
    <input class="coupon_question" id="theControl" name="cadre_number" type="checkbox" onchange="valueChanged()" value="0" > change</input>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="endDiv" style="display:none" align="right">
    <span><label class="radio" id="end1">date</label></span>
    <input class = "radio" value="2016-10-10" checked="" type="date">
    <span><label class="radio" id = "end3">case</label></span>
    <input class = "radio" type="text">
</div>
```

this is the Java Script :-

```
function valueChanged(){
    if($('.coupon_question').is(":checked")){
        document.getElementById("endDiv").style.display = 'block';
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("endDiv").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The problem is when I check the checkbox, nothing happens in the div 'endDiv'!

Comment: I already updated the question

Comment: @Amado What is the error that you are facing ?? Also, your `label` and `div` are closed without any starting tags after `input` element.

Comment: Your code is working for me. Check out the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xhLmk1ou/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#theControl').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#myDiv').show();
        else
            $('#endDiv').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="myDiv" align="right">
    <input class="coupon_question" id="theControl" name="cadre_number" type="checkbox" onchange="valueChanged()" value="0" > change</input>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="endDiv" style="display:none" align="right">
    <span><label class="radio" id="end1">date</label></span>
    <input class = "radio" value="2016-10-10" checked="" type="date">
    <span><label class="radio" id = "end3">case</label></span>
    <input class = "radio" type="text">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not add any jquery.js for using jquery methods. Because it works fine when I added a jquery.js to my html.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, your code is working, but there is some errors like a `label` and a `div` closed without starting tags.

I think you would like to do this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theControl" class="coupon_question" name="cadre_number" onchange="valueChanged()" value="0">
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="endDiv" style="display:none" align="right">
    <label class="radio" for="end1">تاريخ الإنهاء </label>
    <input type="date" id="end1" class="radio" value="2016-10-10">
    <label class="radio" for="end3">سبب الإنهاء</label>
    <input type="text" id="end3" class="radio">
</div>
```

If you are not using jQuery, change your JavaScript `if` condition by this :

```
function valueChanged(){
    if(document.querySelector('#theControl').checked){
        document.querySelector("#endDiv").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        document.querySelector("#endDiv").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onClickHandler()" id="theControl" />

<script>
function onClickHandler(){
    if($('.coupon_question').is(":checked")){
           $("#endDiv").show();
     }

     else{
          $("#endDiv").hide();
     }

}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine!! I think you haven't added jquery library!

```js
function valueChanged(){
        if($('.coupon_question').is(":checked")){
            document.getElementById("endDiv").style.display = 'block';
        }

        else{
            document.getElementById("endDiv").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="myDiv" align="right">
                                    <input class="coupon_question" id="theControl" name="cadre_number" type="checkbox" onchange="valueChanged()" value="0"/ > change
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="endDiv" style="display:none" align="right">
                                            <span><label class="radio" id="end1">date</label></span>
                                            <input class = "radio" value="2016-10-10" checked="" type="date">

                                            <span><label class="radio" id = "end3">case</label></span>
                                            <input class = "radio" type="text">
                                    </div>
```